# How do I flag a question to be a duplicate?

Tags: discussion

I have found the solution to a problem in a question that did not contain any of my search criteria. When I implemented a link in the question containing my search criteria, my link was eliminated and I got this advice:

If you think that this question is a duplicate of another question, please flag it as such. That would be much better than posting an answer, that comes down to a link to the related question. –  David Foerster Mar 22 at 22:30

How can I realize this advice?

Comment: you need more rep, until then leave a comment

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean. Could you add a link to the question you are talking about?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation and http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges

Comment: This is the link with my answer removed: http://askubuntu.com/questions/555623/wifi-is-not-working-on-lenevo-g50-70-ubuntu-14-04-lts-and-no-harware-detection This is the link where I found the answer: http://askubuntu.com/questions/553615/cant-enable-the-proprietary-drivers-for-broadcom-bcm43142-wireless-after-instal

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is:  You can't (yet)

The long answer:

We, higher rep users, sometimes forget how hard it is to get those first 50 points of reputation here on the site, so you shouldn't have been told to do this.  On the other hand, higher rep users also get much more work: they have to review the answer queues, close queues, suggested edit queues, ...  so in this particular case, someone didn't see you were a user with only 1 rep in all the reviewing he was doing, and gave you advise you couldn't follow.

On the other hand, you now know a lot more about the site, so ask questions, answer questions, correct spelling and grammar errors, go hunting for old unanswered questions, ... and you will have that rep in no time!

Happy hunting!